# How to make String value changes when the value of integer which make it changes

Tags: java

How to make `str` value changes when `num` value has changed?

```
int num = 1;
str = num + "%";
```

Comment: You can't do that in java.  If you want the value of `str` to change, you have to change it.

Comment: or i can make String method change it for me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `num` were a field inside a Java class, you could define a getter which returns the desired string:

```
public class YourClass {
    private int num;

    public String getString() {
        return num + "%";
    }

    // ...
}
```